# Proof that products of integers of the form $4k+1$ are of the same form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there an inductive proof on $n$ to show any product of $(4k+1)^n$ is of the same form as $4k+1$. A teacher in my NT class showed a  way to prove it with congruences but I thought there would be a more subtle way .

Comment: How do you mean "subtle"?

Comment: As in by induction not breaking out the congruences mod 4

Answer (score 2):

You don't really mean $(4k+1)^n$, that's only powers of numbers of this form, you want actual products, i.e. $(4k_1+1)\ldots (4k_n+1)$. Start with the base case and let $4k+1, 4j+1$ be such integers. Multiply them.

> $$16kj + 4k + 4j + 1 = 4(4kj+k + j) +1.$$

Now apply induction by noting

$$\bigg((4k_1+1)\ldots (4k_{n-1}+1)\bigg)(4k_n+1) = (4k'+1)(4k_n+1)$$

Comment: So this step is the ' inductive step ' as I had also found -- In terms of n and n+1. U just had done this step for n-1 and n ?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss yes, it works in the same way.

Comment: And yea that was a typo as each 4k_i+1 are unique by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic .

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss not necessarily, only if they are all **primes** is that true. But for example $5\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 29 = 145\cdot 221$ is two representations.

Comment: Yes of course I had meant primes  only as in the statement .thanks Adam .

Answer (score 1):

$$(4k+1)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj (4k)^j=1+4\sum_{j=\mathbf 1}^{n}\binom nj4^{j-1}k^j$$